# Como saber o momento que uma Thread foi finalizada

Tags: java, thread

Tenho a seguinte implementação `javascript` na chamada de um `Thread`.

Gostaria de imprimir no log o momento que a Thread foi finalizada.
Isso é possível?

```
func4 = {
        run: function(){
            atv4();
        }
    };
    r4 = new java.lang.Runnable(func4);
    t4 = new java.lang.Thread(r4);
    t4.start();
    log.info("Iniciei a thread atv4");
    return;
```

Comment: implementação javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que terminar a execução da thread ou até mesmo quando ocorrer algum erro ela vai para o estado `TERMINATED` .

```
if(t4.getState()!=Thread.State.TERMINATED){...}
```

Comment: vou testar e te aviso

Comment: Ok, não sei como vai se comportar na "implementação javascript" mas em java mesmo é assim, qualquer coisa encontramos algo equivalente.