# Como posso matar uma Thread

Tags: java, thread

Gostaria de saber como faço para matar uma Thread.

```
public class thread {

    private static void metodo(){
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    System.out.println("Executando...");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        Thread.interrupted();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Interrompido!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        metodo();
    }

}
```

Não gostaria de dar um simples break no While, gostaria de matar a Thread com métodos dela mesma.

Tenho uma aplicação que necessita parar uma Thread para executa-la novamente, sem executar em paralelo o mesmo método, por esse motivo minha dúvida.

Comment: [Como saber o momento que uma Thread foi finalizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188933/como-saber-o-momento-que-uma-thread-foi-finalizada?rq=1)

Comment: Acho que é mais fácil verificar se a thread acabou do que matá-la. Até porque, quando a thread termina após este break, nao ha mais açao a se fazer.

Comment: Ou pode usar o método [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--)

Comment: Entendi, então é melhor termina-la do que mata-la, vou rever meu método em minha aplicação e dou um retorno, obrigado.

Comment: Consegui resolver, verifiquei minha Thread e ela finalizava, mas quando eu chamava o método que a reiniciava ela acabava entrando em loop, muito obrigado pelas informações. @Articuno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread não se mata, ela tem de parar por vontade própria, então você não escapa de usar um mecanismo de sinal ou flag.

Comment: Entendo, ela tem que terminar por conta própria, obrigado pela resposta curta e objetiva.

Comment: Exatamente, *MESMO QUE HAJA FORMA* de matar uma thread, como Posix threads tem, nunca é aconselhável usar, porque certamente ficarão coisas pela metade, memória não liberada, etc. Threads já são perigosas o suficiente sem isso.